# Оптимизация веб-ресурсов

Tags: html, css

Различные источники рекомендуют при создании таблицы стилей разные методы оптимизации ресурсов, но распространена ли практика сокращения имён идентификаторов для элементов? Так понимаю, что интерпретатору всё равно на идентификатор или класс элемента, а вот сократить файлы на несколько десятков килобайт было бы неплохо, тем самым несколько увеличить скорость загрузки ресурсов с сервера. Например, есть такой код:

```css
.my-class {
  /* style */
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class"></div>
<div class="my-class"></div>
<div class="my-class"></div>
```

И заменить его на:

```css
.mc {
  /* style */
}
```

```html
<div class="mc"></div>
<div class="mc"></div>
<div class="mc"></div>
```

Как относитесь к такому методу? Поправьте в чём-то, если не прав.

Comment: посмотрите здесь - https://habrahabr.ru/post/303174/

Answer (score 1):

Статья в комментарии к вопросу от @soledar10 обязательна к прочтению.
Данная экономия на названиях классов не стоит своей экономии.
Гораздо важней хорошо поддерживаемый код и понятные классы
Данной оптимизацией можно заниматься другими способами, например: gzip, кэширование статики, построением страницы на стороне клиента.
В вашем случае, nginx при меньших затратах на конфиг, сделает достаточно для хорошей оптимизации.

Answer (score 1):

Это бесполезное занятие. Любой алгоритм сжатия (например, gzip) сразу же автоматически сократит все эти классы до ещё более компактных размеров. При именовании стоит придерживаться общепринятых соглашений и руководствоваться удобством при разработке.